# Temporal cost and Spatial cost analysis problem

Tags: java, time-complexity, memory-consumption

Hi I'm new to this and I don't know how to continue analyzing this algorithm that I have done myself, the conclusion I have right now is:

```
T(n) ϵ Ω(2n+1)
     ϵ O(2n+max)

S(n) ϵ Θ(max)
```

- 'max' -> Maximum integer value in the array.
- 'n' -> Is the input size which is the length of the array.

Is this analysis correct?, 'max' will make it linear? and how can I express this better?

Thanks for the help.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpxdK.png)

```
/**
 * Method findUnique2
 * 
 * Finds the unique number inside an array of integers
 * in which there are always 1 unique number and the rest
 * are repeated exactly twice.
 * 
 * NOTE:
 *  This implementation only works with positive integer numbers.
 * 
 * @param v     -> Array with the integer numbers.
 * @return      The unique number.
 */
public static int findUnique2(int[] v)
{
    int max = getMax(v);                                    // Get the maximum number
    int[] repetitions = new int[max+1];                     
    boolean found = false;
    
    // +1 to every position
    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++)
        repetitions[v[i]]++;
    
    /*
     * Finally traversing the array an the position with
     * a 1 is the unique number the rest can be either 0
     * of not used or 2 which is a repeated number.
     */
    int i = -1;
    while(!found)
    {
        i++;
        if(repetitions[i] == 1)
            found = true;
    }
        
    return i;
}

/**
 * Method getMax
 * 
 * Traverse an array of integers and returns the maximum 
 * number stored inside it.
 * 
 * @param v An array of integers
 * @return  the maximum number among the given array.
 */
public static int getMax(int[] v)
{
    int max = v[0];
    
    for(int i=1; i<v.length; i++)
        if (max < v[i])
            max = v[i];
    
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, how does the maximum value have any relevance to this specification: "Finds the unique number inside an array of integers in which there are always 1 unique number and the rest are repeated exactly twice."? Why is it being used to calculate the size of the repetitions array?

Comment: @bliss that's because I follow this steps: First I get the maximum number then I initialize an array with this size+1 then I traverse the array of integers using those values as positions for the other one, I increase that position in one unit, and finally I just have to search the created array with the length of the max+1 for the position with a one, that index is the unique number.

Comment: You said you wrote this code, so why did you make finding the maximum value a step in the first place and why is it used to set the size of the repititions array? What does finding a unique value have to do with the highest integer value in the array? It's an unnecessary iteration and means the repetitions array could be easily undersized/oversized based off the values filling the array.

Comment: Yes all of that's true but I don't know any alternative way taking into account this restrictions: "only use the input arrays, auxiliary primitive variables and even auxiliary arrays.", and of course the XOR solution it's not valid as well.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the problem (and those restrictions are important to note). Your solution is fine and as far as I can tell the analysis is correct - bounded by 2n + max where max is in the range of [1, Integer.MAX_VALUE].

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I have one last question: is the solution linear?

Comment: In terms of Big O analysis, the value of max is ignored and this can be considered a linear-time algorithm, but for practical use it can have a significant impact on performance.